# Handlebarsjs Templates & using html content

Tags: handlebars.js

So, I've got a fairly straightforward handlebars template which an element that looks like this:

```
<div>
  {{include_text}}
</div>
```

I am trying to insert some html like:

```
<table>
....lots of table stuff
</table>
```

When I use the table with the template, what I get looks like:

```
<div>
&lt;table&gt;
... lots of table stuff
&lt;/table&gt;
</div>
```

and I want:

```
<div>
<table>
....lots of table stuff
</table>
</div>
```

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Handlebars (and Mustache) escape the double Mustaches.

Use triple ones

```
{{{include_text}}}
```

From the official GitHub:

> By default, the {{expression}} syntax will escape its contents. This helps to protect you against accidental XSS problems caused by malicious data passed from the server as JSON.
>
> To explicitly not escape the contents, use the triple-mustache ({{{}}}).

Note, the escaping isn't "just there", if your output contains user-entered data, not-escaping might enable them to perform [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS).

Comment: This does not directly answer your question so I'm not adding it to the answer, but depending on what you're doing you might [want to consider partials](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/handlebars-js-part-2-partials-and-helpers)