# Express.js displaying html table with render method

Tags: html, node.js, express

I want to dislay a full table using `res.render` method, is there a way to do this?

what I'm trying:

defining the spot where to send one of my tables.

> main.hbs

```
<html>
         ...
        <div id="main_frame" class="col s12">{{{body}}}</div>
         ...
</html>
```

A basic view file...

> home.hbs

```
...
{{table1}}
{{table2}}
{{table3}}
...
```

my server is querying some datas from my Data Base, I transform it using my `generate_table_from_product_query` function, and display it into `{{{body}}}` section in main.hbs

> server.js

```
...
var rsq;

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "blablabla",
  user: "login",
  password: "pw",
  database: "blablabla"
});

app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
  defaultLayout: 'main',
  extname: '.hbs',
  layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname, 'views/layouts')
}))

app.set('view engine', '.hbs')

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
  response.render('home', {
    table1: rsq
  })
})

app.use((err, request, response, next) => {
  console.log(err)
  response.status(500).send('nope')
})

app.listen(port, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('error', err)
  }

  console.log(`listening port: ${port}`)
})

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("[mysql error1]",err);
  console.log("Connected!");
  var sql_request = 'SELECT * FROM produit'
  con.query(sql_request, function (err, req_result) {
    rsq=generate_table_from_product_query(req_result);
    console.log(rsq);
    console.log("[mysql error]",err);
  });
});
```

here is what i end up with:

[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySrhi.png)

I have tried to use `app.send` but i cant inject it in the right place with this method.

Thanks

Comment: What gets send when you request the page?

Comment: it sends me the all content of my main.hbs + my table, but as a string. you can see it on the image at the bottom of my post, sorry if i wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for how to display html content with Handlebars.
Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16863979/5133130

Comment: thank you, that's exactly what i was looking for.
i feel stupid thow